# pandas.date_range custom frequency

Tags: pandas, date-range

I'm trying to generate a list of dates that capture the 2nd day of the month using the pd.date_range for a rolling 12 month scenario. I don't quite know how to combine frequency alias in documentation to achieve this. Below is where I'm at and the output. I'd like to see

```
['2020-05-02', '2020-04-02', '2020-03-02'...]

pd.date_range(end='2020-06-02',periods=12,freq=)

DatetimeIndex(['2020-05-22', '2020-05-23', '2020-05-24', '2020-05-25',
               '2020-05-26', '2020-05-27', '2020-05-28', '2020-05-29',
               '2020-05-30', '2020-05-31', '2020-06-01', '2020-06-02'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='D')
```

Comment: You need to `sort` first and `groupby` month to get the `nth` day

Comment: do you need `pd.date_range(end='2020-06-02',periods=12,freq='M') + pd.offsets.DateOffset(2)` ? why do you have a reverse index?

Comment: @anky the index doesn't have to be reversed. When I run the script each month I just need to make sure all the reports that ran for the past 12 months on the 2nd are in the list.

Comment: can you edit  the expected output and the question to be clearer, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume that you have defined:

- the end date,
- the number of periods,

as you wrote in your code sample.

To construct your date range use:

- *date_range* with *MS* (month start) frequency,
- combined with *shift* by 1 day.

The code to do it is:

```
rng = pd.date_range(end='2020-06-02', periods=12, freq='MS').shift(1, freq='D')
```

giving:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2019-07-02', '2019-08-02', '2019-09-02', '2019-10-02',
               '2019-11-02', '2019-12-02', '2020-01-02', '2020-02-02',
               '2020-03-02', '2020-04-02', '2020-05-02', '2020-06-02'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

This time *freq* is *None* meaning: There is no "frequency acronym" for
each month starting from the second day of month (there are acronyms for
*month start* and *month end*), but the generated dates are definitely
just as you wish.

Comment: that works perfectly. I had tried to use offset instead of shift with no luck. Thanks

Comment: TIL `Index.shift` , wonder why offset didnt work?, looks similar, but may be i have to play with this more

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`pd.offsets.DateOffset`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset.html) which implements the logic of [relativedelta](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html). It's not vectorized so use a simple list comprehension to get the dates.

```
import pandas as pd

date = pd.to_datetime('June 2, 2020')
pd.Index([date + pd.offsets.DateOffset(months=i) for i in range(12)])

#DatetimeIndex(['2020-06-02', '2020-07-02', '2020-08-02', '2020-09-02',
#               '2020-10-02', '2020-11-02', '2020-12-02', '2021-01-02',
#               '2021-02-02', '2021-03-02', '2021-04-02', '2021-05-02'],
#             dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

---

This method is a bit safer if you need to deal with dates toward the end of the month. February does't have 29 days but the logic of `pd.offsets.Dateoffset` will make it so we still have the last date in February.

```
date = pd.to_datetime('June 29, 2020')
pd.Index([date + pd.offsets.DateOffset(months=i) for i in range(12)])

#DatetimeIndex(['2020-06-29', '2020-07-29', '2020-08-29', '2020-09-29',
#               '2020-10-29', '2020-11-29', '2020-12-29', '2021-01-29',
#               '2021-02-28', '2021-03-29', '2021-04-29', '2021-05-29'],
#              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Comment: do you know why index.shift work instead  : `pd.date_range(end='2020-05-02',periods=12,freq='M') + pd.offsets.DateOffset(2)` or this method

Comment: @anky that seems to work also, unless I'm missing something? (Though I think it would still run into the same problem if you were trying to get the 30th day of each month, since adding a relative offset of days will still roll Jan 31st -> March).

Comment: Thanks , makes sense, Thanks for confirming i am guessing a version problem(*not sure*)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this. Let's say your `df` has the dates

```
df.sort_index(inplace=True)
df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('M')).nth(2) #This is to get the second day
```

Comment: this would be before I've actually pulled the dataset into a df. Creating the list before hand